# Swipe left and right on RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In Xamarin Android I have a screen with a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView's data is filtered by a date. What I want to achieve is that I can use a swipe left and swipe right on the RecyclerView to go to the next or previous date, but let a single tap/click on an item be handled by the RecyclerView itself. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: use ViewPager instead of recyclerView or use gesture recognizer and change a data item on swipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is that I can use a swipe left and swipe right on the RecyclerView to go to the next or previous date, but let a single tap/click on an item be handled by the RecyclerView itself

Basically what you need to do is to embed your `RecyclerView` into `ViewPager`. You can do that by following below steps:

1. Install `Xamarin.Android.support.v7.App` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` nuget packages and their dependencies.
2. Create a Fragment and its layout as page of your `ViewPager` and also responsible for demonstrating the `RecyclerView`.
3. Create the `ViewPager` and its adapter and use it in your `Activity`.
4. Generate `RecyclerView` in Fragment's `OnCreateView`.

Notes: you also need to conduct your data source to get the group information of your data, in order to pass it to `ViewPager`.

For detailed codes, you can refer to my complete demo: [EmbedRecyclerViewToViewPager](https://github.com/elvisxia/EmbedRecyclerViewToViewPager);